# React-Native: Load a Screen by the click of a button

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I am trying to make an App with React-Native and Expo.

The App should display a flat list which is filled with buttons. Every button is supposed to load a new screen that displays text.

The App should display a flat list filled with buttons each one leading to a seperate screen

My problem is how do I implement a button that loads a specific screen (that was not saved before as a separate file but is loaded by app.js).

I have seen tutorials on the render function but didn't know if it was the thing i am looking for.

```js
renderfunction(buttonname){
  render(buttonname){
    return(
    <SafeAreaView>
      <Text>{buttonname}</Text>
    </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
} 
return (
<Button
          onPress={renderfunction}
          title="Learn More"
          color="#841584"
/>
);
```

This is what I have put together from the different tutorials on the render function but this does't work for me and I dont know if this is the right approach to my problem.

**My Question is:** is the render function the right thing for my problem?

I would appreciate your help
Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you meant by `that was not saved before as a seperate file but is loaded by app.js)`?

Comment: I am trying to say that the screen that is linked to is not saved for example as screen1.js but is defined in app.js

Comment: It will have to be a separate component that displays the text no matter what. However it resides in "screen1.js" or is done dynamically in your main app is a design choice. But basically you have a component that takes any text and shows it the way you want. Then pressing the button loads text into that component and shows it on top. My advice is that you look up the basics of how components work and there are loads of tutorials out there showing very much this exact situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The render function is the right thing to use for your case.
I recomend you to read the react.js document on the render function [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html#:%7E:text=The%20term%20%E2%80%9Crender%20prop%E2%80%9D%20refers,implementing%20its%20own%20render%20logic.)

Does that answer your question?

If not Let me know ;)